# Input and output in console inside a loop

Tags: c++, cin, cout, clion

I am making a C++ program to handle books. The user needs to insert the title, price and volumes for 3 books. I don't include the `Book` class in the code as it is not relevant with my problem.

I am stuck in the place where the user needs to input the values inside the loop. When I test the program the console keeps bugging at seemingly random times. (i.e. it shows `"Give book p"` instead of the full sentence and awaits for input).

I read in other answers that I should use `cin.ignore()` after every `cin>>` call in order to ignore the `\n` that is put on the stream when the user presses enter, but it doesn't solve my problem?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string title;
    double price;
    int volumes;

    for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
        cout << "Give book title : " << endl;
        getline (cin, title);
        cout << "Give book price : " << endl;
        cin >> price;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Give number of volumes : " << endl;
        cin >> volumes;
        cin.ignore();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Following is an example of the console :

```
Give book title :
The Hobbit
The Hobbit
Give book price :
12.5
12.5
Give number of volumes :
10
10
Give book title :
Lord of the Rings
Lord of the Rings
Give book price :
12
12
Give number of volumes :
7
7
Give bo
```

As you can see the last sentence is cut off and the console is stuck after.

Comment: I suggest to not mix `getline` and `cin`. It's a recipe for headache as you've found.

Comment: @bolov how else could I handle the input of a string?

Comment: @thelaw Have a look at this (point 2.): https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/1025391

Comment: What is your platform? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I am using CLion IDE on Windows10. I tried it again and again. The place where the sentences are cut is seemingly random every time. Sometimes it also works.

Comment: @thelaw try the solution in the answer below and report back. Probbaly it won'thelp, but try anyway.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I tried it, it wasn't working. Same problem as my code.

Comment: Looks like a platform specific problem.

Comment: Is this a windows command line or a CLion console window?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk It's a CLion console window.

Comment: @thelaw: you asked _how else could I handle the input of a string?_ Answer: `std::cin >> title;`

Comment: @AdrianW That doesn't work if the string (the title) has spaces.

Comment: @MichaelWalz You are right. I downloaded and tried it on Code::Blocks and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Your code also works flawlessly as Linux console application. May be you should just try to run it as windows console application (outside the CLion console, just by running the .exe from a command prompt)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::ws` as a parameter to your `getline()` method to achieve your objective.

The following code will serve your purpose:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string title;
    double price;
    int volumes;

    for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
        std::cout << "Give book title : ";
        std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, title);
        std::cout << "Give book price : ";
        std::cin >> price;
        std::cout << "Give number of volumes : ";
        std::cin >> volumes;
        std::cout<<"Title: "<<title<<" costs "<<price<<" for "<<volumes<<" volumes.\n";
    }

     return 0;
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
Give book title : Harry Potter
Give book price : 12.5
Give number of volumes : 5
Title: Harry Potter costs 12.5 for 5 volumes.
Give book title : James Anderson
Give book price : 45.6
Give number of volumes : 7
Title: James Anderson costs 45.6 for 7 volumes.
Give book title : Lucas Empire
Give book price : 34.5
Give number of volumes : 7
Title: Lucas Empire costs 34.5 for 7 volumes.
```